# How search a file by its name and open it?

Tags: c#

Currently i'm doing a web application project in `ASP.net` `C#`.

Here i have a problem to search a file by its name. Below code is shows were i did, but the problem is, it does not shows the file according to the search name, since it show all file name in directories.

Another problem is, i don't how to open the search files. Can any one help me?

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {
    if (TextBox1.Text != "") 
    {
        string[] pdffiles = Directory.GetFiles(@
        "\\192.168.5.10\\fbar\\REPORT\\CLOTHO\\H2\\REPORT\\", "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        string search = TextBox1.Text;
        ListBox1.Items.Clear();

        foreach(string file in pdffiles) 
        {

            ListBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
        }

        TextBox1.Focus();
    } else 
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('For this Wafer ID Report is Not Generated');</script>");
    }
 }
```

Comment: Well of course your code does nothing with `search` -- you don't use that variable anywhere in your code.

Comment: can you give me a sample code. Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

First you have to use your search variable to filter out intended files

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           string search = TextBox1.Text;

            if (TextBox1.Text != "") 
            {

                string[] pdffiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\192.168.5.10\\fbar\\REPORT\\CLOTHO\\H2\\REPORT\\", string.Format("*{0}*.pdf",search), SearchOption.AllDirectories);

                ListBox1.Items.Clear();
                foreach (string file in pdffiles)
                {

                    ListBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
                }

                TextBox1.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('For this Wafer ID Report is Not Generated');</script>");


            }
        }
```

Now to open selected file.

```
protectecd void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
      string fileName= ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
      Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition",string.Format("attachment; filename={0}",filename));
    Response.TransmitFile(fileName);
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: string fileName= ListBox1.SelectedText; , *.SelectedText is shows error. Which is, Error 2 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedText' and no extension method 'SelectedText' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: My Bad.....change SelectedText to SelectedItem....Updated in answer too

Comment: Thanks. But it still shows error. Which is Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to 'string'.

Comment: You just have to do ToString()

Comment: Thanks. Where could i need to add the ToString. Please help me...

Comment: I have updated in answer.......ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

Comment: Thanks. The .pdf file is cannot open when i click on the ListBox. Can you help me please...

Comment: what do you mean by cannot open?? what is the error you get while reading the file?

Comment: using (FileStream fs = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open)); at semicolon(;) have warning sign...which is  Warning 1 Possible mistaken empty statement. It that because of it..?

Comment: I dont have visual studio handy.....that is why there is lot of syntactical error...but it basically means you have to remove semicolon from that statement..Also, to read and display contents of pdf file, you may have to use iTextSharp library as PDF is binary file..Read more about iTextSharp here http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/341142/itextsharp-read-pdf-file

Comment: Is that possible when i click on listbox the pdf file is open...because i have some confusion about this...please help me...

Comment: you can use Process.Start() to open pdf file.............

Comment: I have updated code in ListBox1 SelectedTextChanged event...

Comment: Thanks. But it still cannot open the pdf file when i click on listbox...how to fix it? Please help me...

Comment: I realized it is asp.net application...user should be able to download and open the file in asp.net...for that I have updated the code again...This should resolve the problem.

Comment: Thanks...Sorry i m always ask the same question. It is show the same result. Which is when i click on listbox the pdf file is not open...please help me...

Comment: please post your updated code....

Comment: i am already post the updated code...please help me...

Comment: I was asking for the code after all this changes....Also, make sure AutoPostBack property of ListBox is set to true..Keep breakpoint in selectedTextChanged event and see if it is hitting...

Comment: What is mean "Keep breakpoint in selectedTextChanged event and see if it is hitting"....still i am cannot open the search pdf file...please help me...

Comment: Check http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/debugging/breakpoints/....I cannot help you unless you tell me what is not working? Like mentioned before,make sure AutoPostBack property of ListBox is true...

Comment: i am already changed what u mentioned. But shows same result. When i click on the listbox were search pdf file, it cannot open...i don't why this happen...plese help me...

Answer (score 0):

you need to use your string search to check if file matches it

```
     protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (TextBox1.Text != "") 
        {
            File[] pdffiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\192.168.5.10\fbar\REPORT\CLOTHO\H2\REPORT\", "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            string search = TextBox1.Text;
            ListBox1.Items.Clear();
            foreach (var file in pdffiles)
            {
                if(file.Name==search)
                {
                ListBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
                }
            }

            TextBox1.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('For this Wafer ID Report is Not Generated');</script>");


        }
    }
```

Also notice you have written the path in GetFiles function

Comment: if(file.Name==search), *.Name is error. it shows, Error 1 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I modified it.. you need to use pdffiles of type file[]. String doesn't have definition for filename

Answer (score 0):

I think the path should be `@"\\192.168.5.10\fbar\REPORT\CLOTHO\H2\REPORT\"`. Also, [Directory.EnumerateFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx) might be more efficient.

Here's how I would search for any files that CONTAIN the searchName

```
using System.Linq;

string reportDirectoryName = "..."; // fill in with full path
string searchName = TextBox1.Text;
if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(searchName))
  return ...;

var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(reportDirectoryName, "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
  .Select(n => Path.GetFileName(n))
  .Where(n => n.Contains(searchName);
ListBox1.Items.Clear();
ListBox1.Items.Add(files);
```

Comment: Yes, the @ prefix means there's no need to double the backslashes